# Symfony4 cache clear throws You have requested a non-existent service "cache.proxy_factory"

Tags: deployment, symfony4, vendor

I am deploying a Symfony4 app. After composer install cache clear throws the following error:

In ContainerBuilder.php line 1011:
You have requested a non-existent service "cache.proxy_factory".

The vendors installed correctly but I can't clear the cache.

vendors are installed with

```
sudo SYMFONY_ENV=prod composer install -d=/var/www/html --no-dev --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader --verbose --profile --prefer-dist
```

Comment: I only get the error when I clear cache on prod, it works fine on dev and staging

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the error was caused by my temp fix of another bug, which I have resolved here - https://github.com/php-cache/issues/issues/137